# Using spatie/media-library, how to rename a collection of uploaded files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I would like to rename a collection of uploaded files, but when I use `addAllMediaFromRequest()` I can't retrieve information from the files.

In this example; I need to know the file extension in order to rename the file.

```php
$files = $post->addAllMediaFromRequest();

$files->each(function (FileAdder $file) {
    $file->usingFileName(Str::random(16) . '.jpg')  // What if it's a png?
         ->toMediaCollection();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since then, they have added the FileNamer class that allow to do what I was trying to achieve. You can can use your own class with the configuration.

**FileNamer.php**

```php
namespace App;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\FileNamer\DefaultFileNamer;

class FileNamer extends DefaultFileNamer
{
    public function originalFileName(string $fileName): string
    {
        return \Str::random(16);
    }
}
```

**media-library.php**

```php
/*
* This is the class that is responsible for naming generated files.
*/
'file_namer' => App\FileNamer::class,
```

**StoreFilesController.php**

```php
$files = $post->addAllMediaFromRequest();

$files->each(fn (FileAdder $file) => $file->toMediaCollection());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a file extension within laravel:

```
$request->file('photo')->extension()
```

To create new file name:

```
        $newFileName = Str::random(20) .'.'.$request->file('photo')->extension();
```

don't forget to import Str class.

then you could rename the uploaded file before storing it easily

```
            $item->addMedia($request->photo)->usingFileName($newFileName)->toMediaCollection('photo');
```

**code tested Laravel v9**

Answer (score 0):

it can be done easly with `toMediaCollection("media_collection_name")`

 in your code:

```
$files = $post->addAllMediaFromRequest(); 
$files->each(function (FileAdder $file) {
    $ext  = $file->extension();//this will get your file extension
    $file->usingFileName(Str::random(16) . '.'.$ext)
         ->toMediaCollection("media_collection_name");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But there no `extension` method in the [FileAdder class](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/main/src/MediaCollections/FileAdder.php). It could be possible to add it with a macro though. But since I asked the question, there's a cleaner way to do it (see my answer)